# How can implement an overlay animation on the following images which are displayed with flexbox?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-animations

The catch is that each image is in a container to constrain their width vertically align them using flexbox.

I can get something to happen when I hover but the position of the animation is incorrect. Most implementations of these types of animations that I have seen make use of position absolute and position relative but I can't seem to wrap my head around how to do it if I am using flexbox.

Please see below:

```css
.logo {
  width: 25vw;
}

// This creates a box around logos that is a square
.logobox {
  width: 25vw;
  height: 25vw;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.logos {
  background: red;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #008CBA;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 10%;
  height: 0;
  transition: .5s ease;
}

.logo-container:hover .overlay {
  height: 10%;
}

.text {
  white-space: nowrap;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="logos">
  <div class="logo-container">
    <a class="logobox" href=''>
      <img class="logo" src='http://via.placeholder.com/350x150' class='img-responsive' alt="">
    </a>
    <div class="overlay">
      <div class="text">
        <p>Spicy jalapeno bacon ipsum dolor amet porchetta hamburger prosciutto ground round andouille. Chicken pastrami pork chop venison sausage. Ribeye drumstick meatball landjaeger alcatra frankfurter. Cow flank tongue, capicola sausage tail andouille
          beef kielbasa shoulder. T-bone drumstick landjaeger, pork belly sausage cupim flank spare ribs filet mignon shankle pastrami fatback. Shankle frankfurter pork loin tail pastrami, meatloaf pork porchetta alcatra hamburger beef bacon pork chop.

        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="logo-container">
    <a class="logobox" href=''>
      <img class="logo" src='http://via.placeholder.com/250x150' class='img-responsive' alt="">
    </a>
    <div class="overlay">
      <div class="text">
        <p>Shank ball tip doner pork belly tenderloin sirloin picanha andouille shankle bacon. Bacon boudin ham, alcatra shank meatball ribeye pork chop short loin. Alcatra porchetta flank, salami biltong chicken tail turducken ham pancetta picanha frankfurter
          bacon. Alcatra brisket ham hock turducken landjaeger. Cow ham hock flank kielbasa pig. Boudin chicken tri-tip corned beef leberkas bresaola fatback ball tip t-bone short loin.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you give the `.logo-container` `position: relative;` so the absolute positioned `overlay` can relate to it<strike>, and then move the `height: 25vw;` to `.logos` the text should render on top of each image</strike>.

*Note, for the purpose if this demo I also changed some of your `height`/`width` values which you likely want to reset/adjust.*

Updated based on a comment

I also changed the positioning on the `text` so it shows properly.

Stack snippet

```css
.logo {
  width: 25vw;
}
.logo-container {
  position: relative;
}
/* This creates a box around logos that is a square */
.logobox {
  width: 25vw;
  height: 25vw;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.logos {
  background: red;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #008CBA;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 0;
  transition: .5s ease;
}
.logo-container:hover .overlay {
  height: 100%;
}
.text {
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="logos">
  <div class="logo-container">
    <a class="logobox" href=''>
      <img class="logo" src='http://via.placeholder.com/350x150' class='img-responsive' alt="">
    </a>
    <div class="overlay">
      <div class="text">
        <p>Spicy jalapeno bacon ipsum dolor amet porchetta hamburger prosciutto ground round andouille. Chicken pastrami pork chop venison sausage. Ribeye drumstick meatball landjaeger alcatra frankfurter. Cow flank tongue, capicola sausage tail andouille
          beef kielbasa shoulder. T-bone drumstick landjaeger, pork belly sausage cupim flank spare ribs filet mignon shankle pastrami fatback. Shankle frankfurter pork loin tail pastrami, meatloaf pork porchetta alcatra hamburger beef bacon pork chop.

        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="logo-container">
    <a class="logobox" href=''>
      <img class="logo" src='http://via.placeholder.com/250x150' class='img-responsive' alt="">
    </a>
    <div class="overlay">
      <div class="text">
        <p>Shank ball tip doner pork belly tenderloin sirloin picanha andouille shankle bacon. Bacon boudin ham, alcatra shank meatball ribeye pork chop short loin. Alcatra porchetta flank, salami biltong chicken tail turducken ham pancetta picanha frankfurter
          bacon. Alcatra brisket ham hock turducken landjaeger. Cow ham hock flank kielbasa pig. Boudin chicken tri-tip corned beef leberkas bresaola fatback ball tip t-bone short loin.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

You could also use Flexbox to center the text in the `overlay`

Stack snippet

```css
.logo {
  width: 25vw;
}
.logo-container {
  position: relative;
}
/* This creates a box around logos that is a square */
.logobox {
  width: 25vw;
  height: 25vw;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.logos {
  background: red;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #008CBA;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 0;
  transition: .5s ease;
  display: flex;                    /*  added  */
  align-items: center;              /*  added  */
}
.logo-container:hover .overlay {
  height: 100%;
}
.text {
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="logos">
  <div class="logo-container">
    <a class="logobox" href=''>
      <img class="logo" src='http://via.placeholder.com/350x150' class='img-responsive' alt="">
    </a>
    <div class="overlay">
      <div class="text">
        <p>Spicy jalapeno bacon ipsum dolor amet porchetta hamburger prosciutto ground round andouille. Chicken pastrami pork chop venison sausage. Ribeye drumstick meatball landjaeger alcatra frankfurter. Cow flank tongue, capicola sausage tail andouille
          beef kielbasa shoulder. T-bone drumstick landjaeger, pork belly sausage cupim flank spare ribs filet mignon shankle pastrami fatback. Shankle frankfurter pork loin tail pastrami, meatloaf pork porchetta alcatra hamburger beef bacon pork chop.

        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="logo-container">
    <a class="logobox" href=''>
      <img class="logo" src='http://via.placeholder.com/250x150' class='img-responsive' alt="">
    </a>
    <div class="overlay">
      <div class="text">
        <p>Shank ball tip doner pork belly tenderloin sirloin picanha andouille shankle bacon. Bacon boudin ham, alcatra shank meatball ribeye pork chop short loin. Alcatra porchetta flank, salami biltong chicken tail turducken ham pancetta picanha frankfurter
          bacon. Alcatra brisket ham hock turducken landjaeger. Cow ham hock flank kielbasa pig. Boudin chicken tri-tip corned beef leberkas bresaola fatback ball tip t-bone short loin.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. This is very close to what I need. I would like it to cover the logobox instead of the logo so that all of the overlays are the same size

Comment: @Chris Then move back the `height: 25vw` to `logobox`...will update my answer in a sec.

Comment: @Chris Updated!

Comment: Thank you @LGSon. I was wondering why the text is also coming in on one line?

Comment: @Chris Updated again...removed positioning on `text`

Answer (score 1):

The `absolute` position is depending on the closest parent `relative` position, if no relative position is mentioned than the relative would be the html/body .
In your case if you want to show it in the container than u have to add a relative position to the container:

```
.logo-container { position: relative; }
```